# Ruby how to parse a Json file with Array keys

Tags: json, ruby

I'm trying to get a Hash from a Json file that has Array Keys, but its return each array key like string.

```
hash = {[10, 10] => [[1, 1], [5, 5]]}
p JSON.parse(hash.to_json) #=> {"[10, 10]" => [[1, 1], [5, 5]]}
```

Maybe i should use YAML, any idea?

Comment: Are your keys arbitrary arrays or are they always arrays of integers? Looks like `#to_json` is calling `[10,10].to_s` to stringify the key before encoding it to JSON. I don't think YAML will help. Marshal won't help either, that's not a good serialization format as it depends on the Ruby version. I'd guess that you're going to end up with some custom format (even if it means double encoding by calling `[10,10].to_json` to stringify the key before JSON encoding the hash, i.e. JSON inside your JSON).

Comment: YAML works very well, returning the hash correctly. I really don't figure out how to use this [10,10].to_json, i think it's the same effect and about Marshal i agree with you.

Comment: Nice, didn't know YAML would do that. You should put that down as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Well, YAML is not JSON so there is not a correct answer, i think @jörgwmittag answer is the correct but the solution for me was to use YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three slightly different versions JSON, as specified by

- [The original JSON.org website](https://json.org/)
- [ECMA-404 – The JSON Data Interchange Syntax](https://ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm)
- [RFC8259 – The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259)

While there are small differences between the three, one thing they all agree on: Object Keys are Strings. Always.

In other words, "a Json file that has Array Keys" *cannot possibly* exist. Whatever you have, it is *either* a JSON file, but then it *cannot* have Array Keys, or it is simply not a JSON file.

Comment: I'm just saving a my own hash, because Marshal sometimes it gets corrupted and i could never solve it